# Label being overriden by the switch, how to fix?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Got a little problem here:
I want to get a toggle switch for language selection. However, the previous label (uk flag) is overriden by the toggle switch. The next label (fr flag) seems to be at the right place despite being not aligned with the radio button on the same axis. Look at what I get:
[Picture of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trt7J.png)

Here is the code in question:

```
<div class="form-group form-switch position-absolute top-0 start-50 translate-middle-x z-3 bg-dark row justify-content-start">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault"><img src="img/gb.svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" /></label>
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault"><img src="img/fr.svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" /></label>
</div>
```

CSS is bootstrap 5.3

Thanks by advance for your time and expertise.

Wishing you an excellent day!

Comment: You will also need to add your css code

Comment: It's bootstrap :)

Comment: @Uxenora we can only see toggle button but not the flag images. It will be great if you will create a working demo with code which will reflect your issue.

Comment: This is what we are seeing by your given code. https://jsfiddle.net/v0fnz5mb/